# Convert 9.78960040953E+12 to a string in PHP

Tags: php, excel, floating-point

I am using Excel Reader to parse an Excel document.
The file contains an ISBN (`978960040953`) and the reader returns `9.78960040953E+12`.

I have set the Excel column type to `text`, but no luck. I have also tried using `(string)` and `strval()`, but still no luck.

One option is to multiply the value so it becomes an integer, but ISBN and ISBN13 have different sizes.

Could anyone help me converting `9.78960040953E+12` to `978960040953`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use floatval and (string) typecasting.
 http://codepad.org/M87DDiXy

```
<?php

$a = "9.78960040953E+12";
$b = (string) floatval($a);
var_dump($b);

?>

Output:
string(13) "9789600409530"
```

Comment: returns 9.78960040953E+12 not 978960040953

Answer (score 3):

You could use the function `strval()` to convert the value to a string. Have a look at the [manual](http://nl.php.net/manual/en/function.strval.php).

Then you could easily manipulate the string to get the exact value you want using the string functions (e.g. `str_replace` and `substr()`).

```
$str = strval($number);
$str = str_replace('.', '', $str);
$str = substr($str, 0, 12);

var_dump($str); //Output: string(12) "978960040953"
```

Comment: already did that and its not working, returns 9.78960040953E+12

Comment: @ntan: Yes it does that exactly. But it is now a string, like you asked for. You could use the function `var_dump()` to see the datatype of the variable like this: `var_dump($str);`. It will output: string(17) "9.78960040953E+12".

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = number_format($number, 0, '.', '');
```

Answer (score 0):

In the excel sheet use the special format (with zip code) example.